# Getting a TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Tags: python

[TypeError Full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLe3T.png)
    #Input of Rectangles

```
print("~" * 60)
print("~" * 60)
lengthOne = str(int(input("Enter the Length of Rectangle #01 = ")));
widthOne = str(int(input("Enter the Width of Rectangle #01 = ")));
areaRecOne = (lengthOne * widthOne)
print("~" * 60)
lengthTwo = str(input("Enter the Length of Rectangle #02 = "));
widthTwo = str(input("Enter the Width of Rectangle #02 = "));

#Output of Rectangles
print("~" * 60)
print("~" * 60)
print("Length of Rectangle #01 = " + lengthOne + " SQ Inches");
print("Width of Rectangle #01 = " + widthOne + " SQ Inches");
print("Area of Rectangle #01 = " + areaRecOne + " SQ Inches");
print("~" * 60)
print("Length of Rectangle #02 = " + lengthTwo + " SQ Inches");
print("Width of Rectangle #02 = " + widthTwo + " SQ Inches");
print("~" * 60)
print("~" * 60)
#Calculation which Rectangle is greater
```

I just started COP1000 class and im stuck on this problem that keeps coming up. Iv tried everything i learned so far with no results.

What i need is for the code to calculate the AREA of the rectangle and stat which Rectangle is greater

But everytime the multiplying keeps saying that

```
    areaRecOne = (lengthOne * widthOne)
    TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share a minimum sample code that causes the exception!

Comment: Both `lengthOne` and `widthOne` are strings. You cannot multiply strings.

Comment: @DYZ yeah I understand that part but iv tried switching to int and float

Comment: the sample of the code is at the top of the picture @KeerthanaPrabhakaran

Comment: What is the purpose of the last `input`? You do not need it.

Comment: @DYZ yeah that last 'input' was a test to see if it would work

Comment: Remove it, and `int()` will work.

Comment: Please post the code instead of a link or an image of code. We really hate when links get outdated. Images are completely useless to people using screen readers, and they are not searchable for anyone.

Comment: Sorry @SJade this was my first posting.

Comment: @DYZ iv tried removing, adding, using 2 or more of 'str' 'int' and 'float' but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're casting your input into an `int` (which is good), and then back into a `str` (this is the problem).

Try

```
lengthOne = int(input('...'))
widthOne = int(input('...'))
```

Also, i'd recommend using `snake_case` in Python; it's a lot more canonical.

Edit:

Here's a simplified version of the program for you to base your implementation off.

```
print("~" * 60)
length = int(input("Length = "));
width = int(input("Width = "));

print("~" * 60)
area = length * width
print("Area = " + str(area))
```

Comment: yeah iv tried removing the [str] and just doing [int] but that didnt work either

Comment: Did you get the same error as before? Can you post your code and the error message?

Comment: yeah i just posted the entire code that im working on.

Comment: yeah that also gave me an error 
    `print("Area = " + area)
    TypeError: can only concatenate str (not 
    "int") to str`

Comment: Yep that almost works. The problem is that i need it to `print` the length, width, and area.
After it `prints` all that its supposed to say which rectangle is greater in area.

Comment: You should give that a try yourself. It will only get harder if you don't take the time to master the basics now.

Comment: oh i know it gets harder. i just cant seem to see or understand what the problem and what im doing wrong.

Comment: the thing is that iv been trying for the past 1.5 hours and with no results figured id get some help lol

Comment: aaaaaand i just figured it out :))) it had to be `floats` for the `input` and `str` them to the `prints` :)))